# Layout Android App

Tags: android

I've got a specific Layout question.
I want to put the RadioButton group on the right side.
I think it's something with layout_weight, but it also might be something else.

Please, help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
.
.
.

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdAbfahrt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:minHeight="33dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp"
            android:text="@string/txtAbfahrt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdAnkunft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:minHeight="33dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp"
            android:text="@string/txtAnkunft"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtZiel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtAnzeigeZeit" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what's your issue? you need the radio button in the right and its text in the left???

Comment: no i the radio buttons should be on the rigth hand side of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a good choice would be to change the `LinearLayout` that encapsulates the `RadioGroup` into a `RelativeLayout` and then use the `android:layout_alignRight` property in xml for the `RadioGroup`. This, of course, doesn't take into account any special reasons for your choice of the `LinearLayout` (for which don't forget to set `android:orientation`).

Comment: I tried this and everything is okey in Android Studio but when I load up the programming a failure is occuring. Maybe its because of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Ok it's working but there's one more problem. Is there anykind of trick to auto-size the whole layout ?

Comment: what do you mean by "auto-size"? You could use match_parent on the RelativeLayout if the auto-sizing you want is on that chunk, otherwise you could use layout_weight.